# Definitive documentation on Java HashSet / HashMap custom object as key?

Tags: java, hashmap, hashset

I'm trying to find the definitive documentation on how to use a custom object as the key for HashMap or as the object stored in HashSet.

From reading various postings, I've somehow discovered that you're supposed to override the two methods equals() and hashCode() in the custom object (e.g. [Overriding equals and hashCode in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)).

However, when I read the Oracle/Sun official Javadocs for [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) and [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), they do not mention overriding these methods at all. Are these instructions buried somewhere else in the documentation? If so, where can I find them?

Answer (score 3):

You don't *need* to override `equals` and `hashCode`, but you do need to have *consistent* `equals` and `hashCode` methods.

That is, if `obj.equals(obj2)`, then it must be the case that `obj.hashCode() == obj2.hashCode()`.  The converse (non-`equals()` objects having unequal `hashCode()` values) should be true as often as possible for good performance, but this is not a requirement and can't always be satisfied if your objects have more than 2^32 states).

The default `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods obey this and have identity semantics - objects are only equal if they are actually the same object (obj == obj2).

If you want value semantics - for example, that two objects with the same state are equal, you should override those methods.

Comment: This does not answer my question. Where is the definitive documentation on using these two methods with HashSet/HashTree? Stackoverflow answers, as much as I appreciate them, are not definitive documentation.

Comment: There is a [good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14970001/149138) below which links to Oracle javadoc for `Object`, which documents them more formally.

Comment: please consider using immutable datatypes!

Comment: What happens if you get a hash collision. Then `obj.equals(obj2) == false` and `obj.hashCode() == obj2.hashCode`.

Comment: @ArwedMett that's "fine" as described in the post. It is only required that object equality _implies_ equal hash codes, not the other way around (it is not required that equal hash codes implies equality). For good performance, however, distinct objects should have distinct hash codes with high probability.

Answer (score 0):

The Collections API describes contracts in terms of equals() and hashCode(). If you want multiple instances of a key to be equal to each other, then you need to override equals() and hashCode(), following the contract specified by the Object class.

The [Set interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) describes its contract:

> More formally, sets contain no pair of elements e1 and e2 such that
>   e1.equals(e2), and at most one null element. As implied by its name,
>   this interface models the mathematical set abstraction.

The contracts for equals() and hashCode() are specified by the Object class.

- Here is the contract for [Object.equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29).
- Here is the contract for [Object.hashCode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29).

In "Effective Java," Joshua Bloch suggests that you always override `hashCode` when you override `equals`, to avoid violating those contracts.

Comment: (1) So the instructions are indirectly reached, right? HashSet leads to Set, which mentions equals(), which is defined in Object. (2) If I use TreeSet instead of HashSet, I only have to override Comparable in the custom object (or provide a Comparator to the TreeSet), right? There is no mention of equals() or hashCode() with TreeSet.

Comment: The contact for `equals` and `hashCode` is defined in `Object` because that's where those methods are defined.  You should define them in a consistent way regardless of whether you are going to use them in a `HashSet` or not.  It wouldn't make sense to have each container define their own contract for these methods, given that any object can choose only one implementation - meaning that all collections should agree on how to use these methods.

Again, your focus on `overriding` is misplaced.  You never have to override any of those methods - just ensure they are consistency defined.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 they are not indirect. As I said in my answer, they are indicated in the documentation for `Set`and `Map`. Those are the interfaces that impose the restrictions, so that's where one wants to look. HashMap, HashSet, TreeSet, are simply implementations and it's not their purpose to specify the contracts, rather to honour them.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 Both `Comparable` and `Comparator` discuss consistency with `equals` (and therefore implicitly `hashCode`).

Answer (score 0):

It's discussed at length in the contract for [java.lang.Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html).

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation for `Set` and `Map`, which are the interfaces they implement.

The requirement isn't arbitrary, it is the only way to guarantee that the methods of the interfaces work as expected - by being able to tell when keys which may be different Java objects should really be treated as the same key or not - for instance, `"abc"` and `"ab" + "c"` are different objects, but the implementation of `equals` ensures they are considered the same key. As to `hashCode`, it is needed to find the meaningful placement inside the data structure that underlies those interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the key must be a Immutable Object.

> If it is mutable, it's hash code can change after adding it to map.
>   Then the map can have problems finding it

[Setting own class as key in java Hashmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665404/setting-own-class-as-key-in-java-hashmap)

Here is an example that illustrates this:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
class Test{

    public int i=0;
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return i;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashMap<Test, String> hm = new HashMap<>();
        Test t1 = new Test();
        hm.put(t1, "found");

        System.out.println(hm.get(t1));

        t1.i=2;

        System.out.println(hm.get(t1));


    }


}

/*
output:
found
null
*/
```