# How to persist a hashtable

Tags: java

I have to persist a hash table which respect the following order : key, value = father, children.

I tried some approaches like

```
for(Acao pAcao : hashtableAcaoDotacao.keySet()){
    for(Dotacao pDotacao : hashtableAcaoDotacao.get(pAcao)){

    }
}
```

Where `Acao` is the key and the value is a ArrayList, but for some reason the hashtable can't find the key pAcao.

Comment: How do you want to persist it?

Comment: the get() should work, from what you've shown.

Comment: Can you post exactly what error you're getting?

Comment: Is hashtableAcaoDotacao a Map<Acao, Dotacao>? If so, then the java API would say that your loop should work I believe. Do you have compiler problems or project setup errors? Can you post the error you're getting. Are you putting elements into the ArrayLists and putting them into the map based on Acao keys?

Comment: I, want to save by jpa by persist the father and then persist his children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you want to use any customize class as key such as

```
Acao pAcao
```

Acao class must implement hashCode and equals methods. Besides that its good practice to use key class as immutable class. It's preferred to used class such as String/Integer to use as key class.

Similar thread - [Setting own class as key in java Hashmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665404/setting-own-class-as-key-in-java-hashmap)

Comment: Well, I find the bug , the problem was that before I trying to get hashtableAcaoDotacao.get(pAcao) I was using merge in this object, so the hashcode changed then I can't get the value by that key.